# Pause in looping HTML5 video

Tags: html, video, html5-video

Is there any way to fix the pause in the looping of an HTML5 video without JavaScript or with "simple" JavaScript?

I have the video looping in the page here:

> http://uweb.txstate.edu/~j_f166/video_testing/html5video.html

Why does it pause?

I'm teaching HTML5 video to my class tomorrow. If there is a workaround without using JavaScript, it would be easier for them. If we need to include JavaScript, what could be a minimal amount of JavaScript code in order to eliminate the pause?

Answer (score 0):

Add the "loop" attribute to your video tag.

```
<video controls loop>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Also, just to state it, the assets on your example page are not found currently. Make sure they are referenced correctly.

Comment: And it's meant to be a full page background looping video.

Comment: That will be handled through CSS and JS to size the <video> tag so it spans the width and height of the browser window. You may want to browse this tutorial for ideas/help: http://demosthenes.info/blog/777/Create-Fullscreen-HTML5-Page-Background-Video

Answer (score 0):

The video doesn't load on the link you provided. 
"loop" attribute should work, you can also try

```
var video1 = document.getElementById("video");
video1.onended = function(e) {
  video1.play();
}
```

where "video" would be the id of your video element

```
<video id="video">
```

Comment: I have loop in the video tag. Sorry, it's only working on Chrome now. I was just going to demo the technique in Chrome for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be processor related. There's a noticeable pause as video frames are buffered upon loop. I've found this pause to be consistent across all browsers, but perhaps there's a workaround. I've used two different methods to loop HTML5 video (webM codec), this:

```
var video1 = document.getElementById("video");
video1.onended = function(e) {
  video1.play();
}
```

or this:

```
<video id="anim" src="animation.webm" poster="frame.png" height="300px" playsinline autoplay muted loop></video>
```

They both seem to perform exactly the same. **Since they don't resolve the pause,** I had to alter the video animation in order to make the pause seem less noticeable. After a couple of months, I've never encountered a better solution. A workaround must exist, though.